# SEO setting category URLs in Magento 2 buggy?

Tags: magento2, category

I've got category URLs like **.*/.html** in Magento2. Ideally I prefer **.*.html**, however I'll settle for **.*/**.

So I go to the Magento admin and change the preference Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> Category URL Suffix to the empty string

[image]

However with caching disabled and a reindex, the category pages are return HTTP 404(page not found). I've even tried deleting all products and categories, then reloading with the revised setting, but still getting 404(page not found).

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow my suggestions for you.

run below commands

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

Delete **var** folder

Delete your **browser cache**.

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is how I know I'm not crazy, because I've done these things and the problems persist. I have some ideas how to troubleshoot, was just hoping there may be something little I've missed.